# app delege didfinishlaunching not called during state restoration in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, appdelegate, state-restoration

I have several setup methods that are essential to running my app.  They are called in the app delegates did finish lanching with options.

I am using state restoration and my app is now failing because when the app is restored, it does not call this method.

Where can I move these methods to be called on state restoration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use also [applicationDidBecomeActive:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a) and/or [applicationWillEnterForeground:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground%3a) for this purpose.

Comment: I put a print in didbecomeactive and it doesn't fire before my decode method, which in turn crashes my app due to the setup not being initialized.